# Slick Carousel with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js

I'm using slick carousel with React.js and when I have been stuck on re-initializing the carousel after the slides have been updated with ajax. The ajax call is triggered on a dropdown change event and DOM is updated, but with the update the slider stops working all slider css classes disappear. What can I do to trigger slick carousel again? I have tried bunch of stuff I read here to use unslick but it does not work, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null
```

Below is the code that works on page load

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (!this.carouselStarted && this.dataIsLoaded()) {
      this.carouselControl.startCarousel();
      this.carouselDidStart = true;
    } 
  }
```

Below is the main code for the component, images are passed as props from the parent:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import _ from 'lodash';
import Carousel from '../../Util/Carousel';

const ResOpt = [{
    breakpoint: 768,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3,
      arrows: true,
      dots: false
    }
  }, {
    breakpoint: 600,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1.5,
      slidesToScroll: 1.5,
      arrows: false,
      dots: false,
      infinite: false
    }
  }
];

class ImagesCarousel extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.carouselDidStart = false;
    this.carousel = new Carousel({
      outerSelector: ".carousel-container",
      innerSelector: ".images-container",
      responsive: ResOpt,
      infinite: false
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (!this.carouselDidStart && this.dataIsLoaded() ) {
      this.carousel.startCarousel();

    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.carousel) {
      this.carousel.destroy();
      this.carousel = null;
    }
  }

  dataIsLoaded() {
    return !_.isEmpty(this.props.images);
  }

  render() {

    let images = this.props.images;

    return (
      <div className="detail-images">

        <div className="carousel-container">
          <div className="images-container">
            {
              (images || []).map((image, index) => {
                return <div key={image.imageId} className="img-item"><img src={image.imageName}  /></div>
              })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ImagesCarousel;
```

And then below is the main carousel class:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import slick from 'slick-carousel';


export default class Carousel {
  constructor(options) {
    this.carouselIsOn = false;
    this.breakpoint = breakpoint;
    this.innerSelector = options['innerSelector'];
    this.outerSelector = options['outerSelector'];
    this.slickOptions = {
      infinite: options.infinite || true,
      slidesToShow: options['slidesToShow'] || 3,
      slidesToScroll: options['slidesToScroll'] || 3,
      dots: true,
      arrows: true,
      appendArrows: options.appendArrows || `${this.outerSelector}`,
      appendDots: options.appendDots  || `${this.outerSelector}`,

    };
    this.startCarousel = this.startCarousel.bind(this);
  }

  startCarousel() {
    const carouselContainer = $(this.innerSelector);
    carouselContainer.slick(this.slickOptions);
    this.carouselIsOn = true;

  }

 addSlides(slide) {
   $(this.innerSelector).slick('slickAdd', slide);
 }

  destroy() {
    $(this.innerSelector).slick("unslick");
  }


}
```

I tried the below, this works but the cloned slides are updated when they come in view and also if the slide number increases after ajax, the layout breaks. So I believe the slides need to be updated but when I add the line:`$(this.innerSelector).slick("unslick");
I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unslick' of undefined error.

```
componentWillUpdate() {
    if (this.carouselControl) {
      this.carouselControl = new CarouselControl(sliderSettings);
    }
  }
```

I modified ComponentWillUpdate methods to one below and now I get a different error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined

```
componentWillUpdate() {

    let slideTpl = function (img) {
        return <div key={img.imageId} className="img-item"><img src={img.imageName} /></div>;
      };

    if (this.carouselControl) {

      // destroy slick and remove html content
      let el = $('.images-container');
         if (el.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
            this.carouselControl.destroy();
            el.html('');

            // create slick again
            this.carouselControl = new CarouselControl(sliderSettings);

            // re add slides
            this.props.additionalImages.map( img => {
              this.carouselControl.addSlides(slideTpl(img));
            });
          }

      this.carouselControl = new CarouselControl(sliderSettings);
    }
  }
```

Comment: can we see more code please? unable to get full context from this. Also please link to library.

Comment: have any details about which object is calling 'add' method? I did have problems when using slick because the images are invisible and have no width/height

Comment: Here is link to another post where I posted more code for this, initially I was getting that "add of undefined" error on page load.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646907/slick-carousel-error?noredirect=1#comment68525433_40646907

Here is a link to slick 
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: I have added more code to my question above.