# slick Cannot read property 'add' of null

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I'm using slick lib. I would like to update slides to show, dots... dynamically.
Here is a part of code:

```
 jQuery('.product_slider').slick({
        infinite: true,
        variableWidth: false,
        adaptiveHeight: false,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000,
        dots: sliderEnableDots,
        slidesToShow: sliderSlidesToShow,
        slidesToScroll: sliderSlidesToScroll,
        speed: sliderScrollSpeed,
        autoplay: sliderAutoPlay,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 780,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 2
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1
            }
        }]
    });
```

But here I get an error: Cannot read property 'add' of null
It seems it occurs when I initialized the slick. Here every click initialized the slick. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: below solution worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884752/error-in-slick-js-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-add-of-null Cheers,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884752/error-in-slick-js-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-add-of-null/37655815