# Slick slider working fine,But gives an unwanted error in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have used multiple slick sliders on the home page of my website and they are working fine. But I got an error in the console, which is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null

Even though the sliders are working completely fine, I want to resolve this issue.

[I tried the solution of this given thread, but it didn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884752/error-in-slick-js-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-add-of-null)

**tried code:**

```
$(".site-caraousel--onesixth-js").not('.slick-initialized').slick();
$(".site-caraousel--onefourth-js").not('.slick-initialized').slick();
$(".site-caraousel--onethird-js").not('.slick-initialized').slick();
```

One of my slick slider codes [among multiple added on the home page]:-

```
$('.site-caraousel--onesixth-js').slick({
    slidesToShow: 6,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    infinite: false,
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow: '<a data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="Previous"><span></span></a>',
    nextArrow: '<a data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="Next"><span></span></a>',
    responsive: [

        {
            breakpoint: 1200,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 5,
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 1023,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 767,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 500,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 360,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Note:- I am unable to find out which slick code caused the issue as multiple codes are there and when I am clicking the error link in the console it leads to me slick.min.js code.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me when I try to update or create a slick object "one more time". For example, after adding new content with Ajax requests.

You need to check if the slider already created before creation. With something like that:

```
let jqObject = $('.site-caraousel--onesixth-js');
if (!jqObject.hasClass('slick-slider')) {
  jqObject.slick({
    // your slick options
  });
}

// Or by checking 'slick-initialized' class. It depends on your code / version.

let jqObject = $('.site-caraousel--onesixth-js');
if (!jqObject.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
  jqObject.slick({
    // your slick options
  });
}

//and probably need to add check if jqObject is have something on the page.
```